# Guide for securing an ajax php webapp

Tags: php, ajax, security

I have a small AJAX application, written in PHP that I did not secure from the start. I would like some recommendations on how to now secure the app, things to implement and check for. I have not found any exhaustive guides on google, and hope that some can be recommended.

It is a small application that connects to and displays records from a mysql database. It is not using any external libraries.

I am unsure about how to protect on passing in variables, such as:

```
if (isset($_GET["cmd"]))
  $cmd = $_GET["cmd"];
```

Should I simply declare $cmd to something before check isset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about securing the app (as opposed to the server/ environment it is on - which I am not really qualified to address)  then I would consider the following:

1. Ensure any user inputs are parsed/cleaned to ensure they can't do things such as [SQL injection attacks](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html). This includes any ajax requests where the user input can be stored on the query string. **In fact anything passed into the app from the query string should be validated/cleaned in this manner**.
2. Do you use any passwords? If so use SSL to stop any packet sniffing. And [hash your passwords in your database with a salt](http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html)
3. A quick Google dug up this which looks pretty good: http://www.securityfocus.com/infocus/1706
4. Some tips on securing user input http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/writing-secure-php-scripts-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

The most important rule when handling user input is: *Validate input, escape output*.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the ultimate security manual? Send me a copy when you find it!

The short checklist:

- SQL vunerabilities?
- Validate your $_GET and $_POST inputs, and remove anything funny
- Lose the get_magic_quotes_gpc() (or whatever it's called)

And of course everything your sys-admin is supposed to do:

- latest version of PHP
- up to date version of MySQL

I'm not sure having no external components makes you more secure automaticly. I use ADODB for PHP, to handle all my SQL stuff. I know it checks for vunerabilities, so I do not have to do it.