# how to secure AJAX interface accepting GET requests

Tags: ajax

any one knows any good article or method to secure AJAX interface that accepts GET requests.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to secure an AJAX app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118910/best-way-to-secure-an-ajax-app)

Answer (score 1):

check the session to make sure the user is authorized, basically just like any other secure web page.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX doesn't accept anything. AJAX is just a way of doing an HTTP request. It's up to you to secure it server side.

Answer (score 0):

A quick SO search turns up this:

[Best way to secure an AJAX app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118910/best-way-to-secure-an-ajax-app)

[Guide for securing an ajax php webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446467/guide-for-securing-an-ajax-php-webapp)

[Securing a remote ajax method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503469/securing-a-remote-ajax-method-call)

Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: One of the questions you linked was the question you replied to!